# Como Fazer o commandButton alterar somente o disabled do input?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Estou com um projeto de cadastro e nele gostaria de visualizar os dados já cadastrados mas mantendo os inputs não editáveis ate que eu clique no botão editar, desta forma habilitando que eu altere os dados, mas como eu fiz, os inputs são resetados e não é possível atualizar o cadastro.

Coloquei o atributo `disabled` nos inputs e seu valor é modificado através de um método `boolean`

Ex:

```
<h:form id="cadastro">
                    <p:messages id="messages" />
                    <p:fieldset legend="Cadastro Pessoal">
                        <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-content-end">
                            <p:commandButton value="Editar"
                                rendered="#{cadastroBean.eEditavel}"
                                action="#{cadastroBean.ativaCampos}" immediate="true" 
                                update="@form"
                                process="@this cadastro" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid ui-fluid mt-3 ">
                            <div class="col-12 md:col-6">

                                <div class="field">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="Nome:" for="nome" />
                                    <p:inputText id="nome" value="#{cadastroBean.pessoa.nome}"
                                        validator="#{validators.validaInput}" required="True"
                                        requiredMessage="Necessário Nome"
                                        disabled="#{cadastroBean.eEditavel}">
                                        <f:ajax event="blur" render="messages" />
                                    </p:inputText>
                                </div>
```

Método no Bean, como padrão o `eEditavel` é `false`:

```
public void ativaCampos() {
        eEditavel = false;
        
    }

public void carregarCadastro(Cadastro cadastro) {
        this.pessoa = cadastro;
        eEditavel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente isso tem relação com os ciclos de vida dos beans do JSF.

Se o seu bean tiver uma requisição `@RequestScoped`, então os dados que ele tem serão perdidos assim que a requisição estiver finalizada, o que você pode resolver alterando para o `@ViewScoped`, que permite a persistência dos dados até que você recarregue a página ou saia dela, ou qualquer outro escopo que mantenha o bean vivo.

Você pode utilizar, no `commandButton`, os atributos `partialSubmit="true" process="@this"` para evitar que todo o form seja enviado na requisição, somente o botão que vai chamar o método para habilitar a edição.

```
<p:commandButton value="Editar" rendered="#{cadastroBean.eEditavel}"
action="#{cadastroBean.ativaCampos}" immediate="true" update="@form" 
process="@this cadastro" />
```

Ou então poderia utilizar JavaScript para atingir o mesmo propósito. A [biblioteca JS do Primefaces](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/) é bem rica em funcionalidades. O componente `<p:inputText>` possui [métodos](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_PrimeFaces.PrimeFaces.widget.InputText.html) que permitem ativar/desativar o campo. Para tal, bastaria adicionar um:

```
PF('inputTextWidgetVar').enable()
```

E atribuir uma variável de Widget no componente:

```
<p:inputText widgetVar="inputTextWidgetVar" />
```